# Qt Quick which component to use to display multi column list

Tags: qt, qml

I am new to QT Quick and am porting a music book from a web app to Qt Quick.  The user can click on a letter "A" or "B" and then the bottom of the screen will show all songs that begin with "A" or "B".  (My input data is in JSON but I could also change that to XML if it made the GUI easier to code.)

For example, if I the user clicked "X" and I have 12 songs to display I would want the columns to display the songnames as

```
XXXXXXX     XYYYYY     XZZZZZ
XXXXXXX     XYYYYY     XZZZZZ
XXXXXXX     XYYYYY
XXXXXXX     XYYYYY
XXXXXXX     XYYYYY
```

This is the behavior on the website.
What control in the QML library would I use for this type of layout?  I looked at Row, Column, Flow and Grid but don't think they will provide the exact functionality.  Flow will display left to right and then wrap to the next row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can set top to bottom on `Flow` as per documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flow.html#flow-prop

> flow : enumeration This property holds the flow of the layout.
>
> Possible values are:
>
> Flow.LeftToRight (default) - Items are positioned next to to each
>   other according to the layoutDirection until the width of the Flow is
>   exceeded, then wrapped to the next line. Flow.TopToBottom - Items are
>   positioned next to each other from top to bottom until the height of
>   the Flow is exceeded, then wrapped to the next column.